# Huge problems on a class template about Television simulation

Tags: python, string, function, class, init

Good day everyone, so here's the problem.

I was working on a class method related project to simulate a Television menu.

If you enter 0, it should exit the main function. If you enter 1, it should power off the Television and display a message saying whether or not the TV has been turned on or off. If you enter 2, you'll have to enter a channel number that are bigger than 0 and less than 500 in order to switch into that channel. If you enter 3 you should raise your volume, while entering 4 should lower the volume with texts displaying telling you if the volume change has succeeded or not. Also, the volume can't be lower than 0 or higher than 10.

But everything aside from option 0 and 3 is having severe issues.

When I enter 2 to try to get the channels set up, it displays nothing.

When I enter 4, the texts were displayed but the volume itself didn't change and always stays in 5 no matter what.

When I enter 1, it always displays that the TV has been turned off, and never displays it being turned on. But when I entered 3 the volume is still being increased successfully while it should fail and display a text describing that the volume increase should have failed.

And here's the code:

```
class Television:
    
    
    """Get yourself some televisions"""
    def __init__(self, channel, volume, is_on):
        self.channel = channel
        self.volume = volume
        self.is_on = is_on
        is_on = False
    
    def __str__(self):
      string = "\nStatus: "
      string += "\nChannel " + self.channel
      string += "\nVolume" + self.volume
      if is_on == True:
        string += "\n" + self.is_on
      return string
      
    def toggle_power(self):
      if self.is_on == True:
        self.is_on += False
        print("The TV has been turned off.")
      if self.is_on == False:
        self.is_on += True
        print("The TV has been turned on.")
      
    def get_channel(self):
      print("You're currently in channel", self.channel)
      return self.channel
      
    def set_channel(self):
      if self.is_on == True:
        self.channel = float(input("Enter the channel number you want to switch to."))
        if current < 500 and current > 0:
          print("You have been switched to channel", self.channel)
        else:
          print("Channel not found.")
      elif self.is_on == False:
        print("The TV has been turned off.")
      
    def raise_volume(self):
      if self.is_on == True:
        if self.volume < 10:
          self.volume += 1
          print("The volume has been successfully increased. Your current volume is", self.volume)
        else:
          print("The attempt to raise the volume level was unsuccessful.")
      elif self.is_on == False:
        print("The TV has been turned off.")
      
    def lower_volume(self):
      if self.is_on == True:
        if self.volume > -1:
          self.volume +- 1
          print("The volume has been successfully lowered. Your current volume is", self.volume)
        else:
          print("The attempt to lower the volume level was unsuccessful.")
      elif self.is_on == False:
        print("The TV has been turned off.")



def main():
  choice = 1
  tv1 = Television(1, 5, True)
  while choice != 0:
    choice = int(input("""0 - Exit

1 - Toggle Power

2 - Change Channel

3 - Raise Volume

4 - Lower Volume

"""))
    if choice == 1:
      tv1.toggle_power()
    if choice == 2:
      tv1.get_channel
      tv1.set_channel
    
    if choice == 3:
      tv1.raise_volume()
    if choice == 4:
      tv1.lower_volume()
main()
```

These issues are just severe...Please tell me if there are ways to fix them!

Comment: The error message is fairly self explanatory - at `while choice != 0`, choice has not been assigned a value. Just initialize it to 0 (`choice = 0`) before this line.

Comment: @SuperStormer Thank you, I'll be right back and check it out.

Comment: I'd recommend initializing it to something other than zero but yeah.

Comment: Thank you both guys, now I'm having new questions....